# Is deleting a region of memory via a pointer located within the region safe?

Tags: c++, memory

so this is a bit of a weird question, but if I was to have some sort of class whose entire purpose it to delete itself by keeping a pointer to the allocator that allocated the memory:

```
struct SelfDeleter
{
    std::pmr::memory_resource* m_allocator;
    void delete_self()
    {
        m_allocator->deallocate(this, sizeof(SelfDeleter), alignof(SelfDeleter));
    }
};
```

And we then run it:

```
int main()
{
   std::pmr::memory_resource* resource = std::pmr::get_default_resource();
   SelfDeleter* obj = reinterpret_cast<SelfDeleter*>(resource->allocate(sizeof(SelfDeleter), alignof(SelfDeleter)));
   obj->m_allocator = resource;
   obj->delete_self();
   return 0;
}
```

Is this safe to do? I know in order to make the call to deallocate the value of m_allocator will be loaded into a register, but I'm mostly concerned about the possibility that the compiler might later discard that value and then try and load it again later from m_allocator on the heap during the deallocate function, which may have been deleted.

I've tried running this code and it appears to work, but I'm unsure if that's entirely coincidental. I know that I could force m_allocator to be copied into the stack by use of std::launder and therefore make sure the value doesn't get reloaded from the heap but I'm not sure if I *have* to for guaranteed safe behaviour. Obviously accessing the pointer again after deallocation is unsafe but for this question I'm just concerned with the call to the deallocation function

Comment: I'm not sure where you think compiler would load `m_allocator` after deallocation.

Comment: and multiple pointer can point to same object, the allocator still alive after the object destroy.

Comment: My concern is that during the call to deallocate, the value pointed to by `m_allocator`, which would be `this` inside the deallocate function, won't be copied onto the stack, and therefore would have to be reloaded from the heap, not that the actual allocator would be destroyed, just that the pointer might've been overwritten

Comment: the value pointed to by `m_allocator` is not `this` though

Comment: simply put, this'd probably safer than `delete this` and that is safe.

Comment: I'm talking about the internals of the `deallocate` function, not the `delete_self` function. The deallocate function is likely more complicated than `delete this`

Comment: it has nothing to do with any pointer point to it though.

Comment: you can aswell overwrite `m_allocator` inside any function. and it would not effect what instance you call it on.

Comment: Changing m_allocator to another value would absolutely change what instance `deallocate` is being called in? If you changed it to nullptr that's definitely going to effect the result of the program?

Comment: not the current calling one as in this case.

Comment: what you've done is not that different than set it to nullptr inside `deallocate`

Comment: It'll depend on how exactly the deallocation is implemented. If it simply zeros the memory at the address then your 'obj' pointer will be left dangling, so if you tried to dereference it, then your program would break. So it's not exactly safe, this problem is because you are using heap allocation to create objects which returns references. Try writing classes that only use stack memory.

Comment: Thank you! So inside the body of `deallocate`, any use of `this` is essentially just referring to m_allocator in this case? And therefore if we did hypothetically zero it out in the deallocation and after tried to access one of the allocator's member variables, that would be potentially breaking behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure how the memory allocator works internally but it usually they just return to you a block of memory to do what you want with. Yeah if you zero the memory it's allocated you and then access a member, what happens is called undefined behaviour because depending on what type the member is and how you use it could cause massive errors and crashes :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is a correct implementation. On a single threaded application there are no unexpected side effects. The big question is, what is your use case? If you wan't more robust code: Zero the memory before deallocating the objects helps a lot.